# issues running socket.io over an apache proxy

Tags: socket.io

Recently i moved from using port numbers to an apache proxy, and now i get the following browser console errors:

> VM6:1 GET https://comptonpeslonline.com/proxyPort20005/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NX 400 (Bad Request)
>
> VM6:1 POST https://comptonpeslonline.com/proxyPort20005/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NX 400 (Bad Request)

and my apache log file is filling up with these messages:

> [Mon Mar 02 18:25:03.199849 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 28494] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:20005 (localhost) failed
>
> [Mon Mar 02 18:25:03.199892 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 28494] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost) for 5s
>
> [Mon Mar 02 18:25:03.199898 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 28494] [client 71.223.254.40:50269] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost, referer: https://example.com/proxyPort20005/

--

I did find one interesting difference between using ports and proxies.  using the port number, when I entered the following:

> https://example.com:8005/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling

these results came back in the browser window:

> 96:0{"sid":"XXXX","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}

but when I tried the same using the proxy:

> https://example.com/proxyPort20005/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling

I see suspicious looking results, very different from when i used the port number:

> {"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"}

the strange thing is that everything appears to be working fine, except for all the error messages.

my httpd.conf is configured like this:

```
 ## 2020-03-02 - tried acquire
 ## 2020-03-02 - tried disablereuse=on
<Location /proxyPort20005/>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:20005/ Keepalive=On retry=5 timeout=600
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:20005/
</Location>
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on what i might try next?

thank you all very much.

Answer (score 2):

After much time and effort, i have two solutions:

```
##  thank you lopezdonaque @ https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1696

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
RewriteRule /proxyPort3030/(.*) ws://localhost:3030/$1 [P,L]

<Location /proxyPort3030/>
    ProxyPass               http://localhost:3030/
            ## it seems to work fine without proxyPassReverse ??
    ProxyPassReverse        http://localhost:3030/
</Location>

const socket = io.connect
            (
                    {       'path'  : window.location.pathname + 'socket.io'
                    ,       'transports'    : ['websockets', 'polling']
                    }
            );
```

this works as well, however, I wanted both WebSockets and Polling working, this example only has polling:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
  <Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Proxy>
</IfModule>

ProxyPass          /proxyPort3030/                 http://localhost:3030/
ProxyPassReverse   /proxyPort3030/                 http://localhost:3030/
ProxyRequests off

const socket = io.connect
            (
                    {       'path'  : window.location.pathname + 'socket.io'
                    ,       'transports'    : ['polling']
                    }
            );
```